# MySQL 8.2 AES_ENCRYPT IV is not affecting the results

Tags: sql, mysql, encryption, xampp

I using XAMPP with MySQL 8.2 and I have statements like this:

```
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key',`IV`,'hkdf') ) WHERE  id = 1;
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key',`IV`,'hkdf') ) WHERE  id = 2;
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key',`IV`,'hkdf') ) WHERE  id = 3;
```

The `IV` is a unique data that already defined in the table. I am getting the same value for these statement (like these 3 statements all output: 123), found out that maybe the `IV` is not affecting the result.

And I tried to handmade `IV` but its getting the same result too.

```
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key','abc','hkdf') ) WHERE  id = 1;
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key','acb','hkdf') ) WHERE  id = 2;
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key','bca','hkdf') ) WHERE  id = 3;
```

But if I add the salt parameter after 'hkdf', the result will be affected by the salt.

```
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key',`IV`,'hkdf',`IV`) ) WHERE  id = 1;
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key',`IV`,'hkdf',`IV`) ) WHERE  id = 2;
UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key',`IV`,'hkdf',`IV`) ) WHERE  id = 3;
```

Want to know why my `IV` parameter is not affecting the result? Or how can I make it affective?
`` UPDATE Table SET `column` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('plaintext','key',`IV`,'hkdf') ) WHERE  id = 1; ``
Thank you!

Comment: [XAMPP is MariaDB, not MySQL](https://github.com/ApacheFriends/xampp-control-windows/issues/7), and [MariaDB only added the extended syntax of AES_ENCRYPT in 11.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aes_encrypt/).

Comment: I've edited the title and tags to make it more clear the OP is using MariaDB, not MySQL. We should all think of these two products as different implementations, not necessarily compatible.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: I don't think OP is using MariaDB. MariaDB doesn't support kdf_name and salt.

Comment: @EdwinNG, would you please clarify? Run this query: `SELECT VERSION();` and tell us what it returns.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Sorry the the confusion. I use XAMPP control panel and start the MySQL module, it will lead me to phpmyadmin page. Select version returns 8.2.0. I think I should be using MySQL?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've edited the title and tags again. It's good to be clear when you ask questions exactly which version you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't mention which [block-encryption-mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_block_encryption_mode) you're using, I assume it is the default, which is ECB (Electronic Codebook).

In contrast to other block encryption modes such as CBC or GCM, ECB does not require an initialization vector and therefore the passed value with the content of IV column will be ignored:

```
SELECT @@block_encryption_mode;
+-------------------------+
| @@block_encryption_mode |
| ----------------------- |
| aes-128-ecb             |
+-------------------------+

SET @a:=AES_ENCRYPT("mytext", @key, @iv);
SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+---------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message             |
| ------- | ---- | ------------------- |
| Warning | 1618 | <IV> option ignored |
+---------+------+---------------------+
```